# Is there any way to make each print have different pattern

Tags: java, string, char

How do I make a loop on this pattern which can make the pattern can become like this (which the X will replace the _)
I know I can make it like define n=0 and n+2 for each loop and increment by 2, but it come out with problem which it will become like this

```
XX_XXXXXXXXXX    
XX_X_XXXXXXXX    
XX_X_X_XXXXXX
```

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String a = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    char[]abc = a.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        int n=2;
        abc[n]='_';
        a = String.valueOf(abc);
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
}
```

The code I posted above is the code without the loop
I expect the output will be like this if the loop is successful

```
XX_XXXXXXXXXX    
XXXX_XXXXXXXX    
XXXXXX_XXXXXX
```

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated

Comment: HINTS: 1) You need to refresh `abc` back to all X's _each time_ around the loop, not just once before the loop; 2) the underline will go at position `i + 2`

Answer (score 2):

You should do following to make your output look as expected:

1. Use loop variable `i` instead of block variable `n` as array index. This ensures the position of `'_'` is shifted on each step
2. After printing each step revert placed `'_'` in the array back to `'X'`. This makes `'_'` shifting instead of repeating

I intentionally do not give any code because the problem feels more like training task, and  figuring out correct instructions should do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add and hold the places you want to have `'_'` character by using a `List` of integers. Each time the main loop runs, you can access the intended places by a nested-loop. In the end, you add the next `'_'` place which should be used in the next time.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    char[]abc = a.toCharArray();

    List<Integer> placeHolders = new ArrayList<>();
    placeHolders.add(2);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < placeHolders.size(); j++)
            abc[placeHolders.get(j)]='_';

        System.out.println(abc);

        //Accessing the latest record of the list
        placeHolders.add(placeHolders.get(placeHolders.size()-1)+2);

    }
}
```